# MySQL only works with: skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I forgot the root password, so followed a few different methods to reset, which eventually worked.

Now I am unable to create new databases on PHPmyAdmin, the message "no privileges" is displayed.

So I try to add all the permissions to ROOT again using:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But then I get the error:

```
#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

So I remove the "skip-grant-tables" from my.ini, then my MySQL based sites stop working.

Have I officially fudged it up?

Comment: Have you tried to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restarted your mysql server.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I haven't run FLUSH PRIVILEGES, but I have restarted.

Comment: @KristerAndersson The flush worked. Thank you, add as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you flush the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html):

> **FLUSH PRIVILEGES**
>
> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database.
>
> The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT and CREATE USER statements. This memory is not released by the corresponding REVOKE and DROP USER statements, so for a server that executes many instances of the statements that cause caching, there will be an increase in memory use. This cached memory can be freed with FLUSH PRIVILEGES.