# MySQL works only with --skip-grant-tables and can't go away from that. Linux

Tags: mysql

I was looking on almost every solution which I found on the web, but I still have this issue.
I can connect to mysql (either in terminal or phpmyadmin) when I run --skip-grant-tables, but without it it is totally not working (I am getting 1045 access denied).

I found this: [MySQL only works with: skip-grant-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312585/mysql-only-works-with-skip-grant-tables) but I can't run it, because I can only access mysql with --skip grant tables.

Any solutions? I really googled and tried a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a glance seems it's mysql user permissions problem. if, say, you connect with uname userone, it's just that userone does not have certain permissions on the tables and therefore you have to pass 'skip-grant-tables' option. easiest approach - log as root (admin or whatever god-like-mysql user) and grant your normal user (userone) the missing permissions. See this, there is example under "Account names and password" 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: I finally totally removed MySQL and reinstalled it and it helped.

Comment: Well, now as this is not an issue anymore - try to reproduce the problem and you'll witness the educational side of bugs and troubles in general :) Add another user, remove it's permissions and try log with it and with --skip grant tables, then without the option, then give the permissions back (using the other user) and try again.